# Dropwizard service not starting with following stacktrace

Tags: rest, dropwizard

I was getting the following stacktrace. The possible reasons were not available on the web

```
    Exception in thread "main" MultiException[javax.servlet.ServletException: name@337a8b==com.hubspot.dropwizard.guice.GuiceContainer,1,false, javax.servlet.ServletException: com.hubspot.dropwizard.guice.GuiceContainer-10d98940@327a1ad9==com.hubspot.dropwizard.guice.GuiceContainer,1,false]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ServerCommand.run(ServerCommand.java:43)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:43)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:76)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:70)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:72)
    at MyService.main(MyService.java:45)
javax.servlet.ServletException: name@337a8b==com.hubspot.dropwizard.guice.GuiceContainer,1,false
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.doStart(InstrumentedHandler.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.doStart(StatisticsHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ServerCommand.run(ServerCommand.java:43)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:43)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:76)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:70)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:72)
    at MyService.main(MyService.java:45)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.hubspot.dropwizard.guice.GuiceContainer.initiate(GuiceContainer.java:70)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:540)
    ... 36 more
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.hubspot.dropwizard.guice.GuiceContainer-10d98940@327a1ad9==com.hubspot.dropwizard.guice.GuiceContainer,1,false
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.doStart(InstrumentedHandler.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.doStart(StatisticsHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ServerCommand.run(ServerCommand.java:43)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:43)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:76)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:70)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:72)
    at MyService.main(MyService.java:45)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.hubspot.dropwizard.guice.GuiceContainer.initiate(GuiceContainer.java:70)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:540)
    ... 36 more
```

All my injectable arguments were correct and that piece of code (initializing injectable objects) was passing in debugger.

Answer (score 1):

The reason was,

```
@POST
@Path("/trigger")
@Timed
@ApiOperation("trigger a event")
@UnitOfWork
```

I was using the same @Path in two API's, as a result of which dropwizard startup was failing.

Answer (score 1):

Your question and answer helped me with my problem. For my dropwizard service I was getting a similar error

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer-581f1f40@e6b6b7b3==com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer,1,false
```

`Caused by: com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException`

The solution turned out to be the same. My service did not start up because I had 2 @POST in the same resource/path. Changing that started my service.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the issue because I have not used this annotation `@PathParam("something")` before the method argument in the API.

eg:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/internal/something/{var1}/{var2}")
    public Response doOperation(@NonNull @PathParam("var1") String var1, @NonNull @PathParam("var2") String var2) {

        // operation
    }
```